# Where can I find an updated list of all Free GNU/Linux distribution iso?

Tags: linux, live-usb, iso, download, unetbootin

I want to test several linux versions.

Is there any database that is constantly being updated where I can find this list of iso?

I thought about mining in the source code of an iso USB installer if no official list of utility exists (such as `unetbootin`)

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I know of that comes close to what you're asking for would be Distrowatch.com, but you won't find the ISO's hosted there, you will however find out about the latest releases of many distributions and where they are officially hosted. There are currently around 800+ active distributions of linux according to Distrowatch.